# How to write data into a CSV file using python?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

I'm wrinting trying to write the following data into a csv file.The data is employdetails

> name1-surname1-place1
>
> name2-surname2-place2
>
> name3-surname3-place3
>
> name4-surname4-place4

I want the output to be on CSV files one below the other on separate rows.

> **I have written the below code**
>
> reader = csv.reader(file)
>
> op = open(path+"op.CSV", "wb")
>
> String=list[0] + "-" + list[1] + "-" + list[2] + "-" + list[4]
>
> ```
>  op.writer(String)
> ```

PLEASE HELP.

Thanks in advance.

-KD

Comment: If it's a CSV file, shouldn't you be putting commas in it?

Comment: CSV can and does have many different characters used as delimiters. For example in some countries , is actual the symbol for decimals. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: Huh!   Learn something new every day! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i've understood your question well, you are looking for this:

```
>>> import csv
>>> employees = [
...     'name1-surname1-place1',
...     'name2-surname2-place2',
...     'name3-surname3-place3',
...     'name4-surname4-place4',
... ]
>>> with open('out.csv', 'w') as out:
...     writer = csv.writer(out)
...     for e in employees:
...         writer.writerow(e.split("-"))
... 
>>> 
>>> 
host:~$ head out.csv 
name1,surname1,place1
name2,surname2,place2
name3,surname3,place3
name4,surname4,place4
```